# Как передать данные в другой класс из метода, подключенного к БД?

Tags: java, база-данных, коллекции, arraylist

Есть класс, который подключается к БД. В нем есть метод считывания, который сразу передает данные в коллекцию:

```
public class Basa_Dannyh {

public static ResultSet resSet;    

public static void ReadDB() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException
{
    resSet = statmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM nachaltest");

    while(resSet.next()) 
    {
        int id = resSet.getInt("id");
        String  quest = resSet.getString("quest");
        String  ansver1 = resSet.getString("ansver1");
        String  ansver2 = resSet.getString("ansver2");
        String  ansver3 = resSet.getString("ansver3");
        String  true_ansver = resSet.getString("true_ansver");

        ArrayList<String> test_collection = new ArrayList<String>();
        test_collection.add(quest);
        test_collection.add(ansver1);
        test_collection.add(ansver2);
        test_collection.add(ansver3);
        test_collection.add(true_ansver);

        for (int i = 0; i<test_collection.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println(test_collection.get(i));
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Подключение к этому методу в другом классе происходит так:

```
Basa_Dannyh.ReadDB();
```

Мне нужно передать коллекцию в другой класс. Как это сделать? Через создание экземпляра класса:

```
Basa_Dannyh bd = new Basa_Dannyh();
```

Не получается. Пытаюсь стандартно подтянуть таким образом:

```
Basa_Dannyh bd = new Basa_Dannyh();
System.out.println(bd.test_collection.get(1)); //например
```

Ошибка. Не видит `test_collection`.

Answer (score 1):

Вот здесь попробуйте вернуть вместо `void` - `ArrayList<String>`

```
public class Basa_Dannyh {

public static ResultSet resSet;    

//readDB исправил с маленькой буквы
public static ArrayList<String> readDB() throws ClassNotFoundException,         SQLException
{
    resSet = statmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM nachaltest");
    ArrayList<String> test_collection = new ArrayList<String>();//здесь мы вывели объявление массива из цикла
    while(resSet.next()) 
    {
    int id = resSet.getInt("id");
    String  quest = resSet.getString("quest");
    String  ansver1 = resSet.getString("ansver1");
    String  ansver2 = resSet.getString("ansver2");
    String  ansver3 = resSet.getString("ansver3");
    String  true_ansver = resSet.getString("true_ansver");


    test_collection.add(quest);
    test_collection.add(ansver1);
    test_collection.add(ansver2);
    test_collection.add(ansver3);
    test_collection.add(true_ansver);

    for (int i = 0; i<test_collection.size(); i++) {
        System.out.println(test_collection.get(i));
        }
    }
     return test_collection;//здесь возвращаем
  }

}
```

Получить можно так

```
<!!-Basa_Dannyh bd = new Basa_Dannyh();-!!>//виноват, действительно у вас метод static, можно не создавать новый объект.
ArrayList<String> newArrayList = Basa_Dannyh.readDB();//тогда так
```

Answer (score 1):

У Вас `Basa_Dannyh.ReadDB()` статический метод, который ничего не возвращает.

```
Basa_Dannyh bd = new Basa_Dannyh();
System.out.println(bd.test_collection.get(1));
```

А здесь вы создаете новый объект класса, и пытаетесь получить доступ к коллекции `test_collection` (к полю), которого у Вас не существует. Отсюда и ошибка.
Соответственно Вам нужно изменить возвращаемое значение у метода `Basa_Dannyh.ReadDB()`:

```
public static ArrayList<String> ReadDB() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException
{
    ArrayList<String> test_collection = new ArrayList<String>();
    resSet = statmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM nachaltest");

    while(resSet.next()) 
    {
       int id = resSet.getInt("id");
       String  quest = resSet.getString("quest");
       String  ansver1 = resSet.getString("ansver1");
       String  ansver2 = resSet.getString("ansver2");
       String  ansver3 = resSet.getString("ansver3");
       String  true_ansver = resSet.getString("true_ansver");

       test_collection.add(quest);
       test_collection.add(ansver1);
       test_collection.add(ansver2);
       test_collection.add(ansver3);
       test_collection.add(true_ansver);

       for (int i = 0; i<test_collection.size(); i++) {
          System.out.println(test_collection.get(i));
       }
    }
    return test_collection;   
}
```

И использовать этот **статический** метод:

```
ArrayList<String> collection = Basa_Dannyh.ReadDB();
```